# How to get the length of a cell value in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a pandas dataframe:

```
idx Event
0   abc/def
1   abc
2   abc/def/hij
```

Run: `df['EventItem'] = df['Event'].str.split("/")`

Got:

```
idx EventItem
0   ['abc','def']
1   ['abc']
2   ['abc','def','hij']
```

Want to get the length of each `cell`, run `df['EventCount'] = len(df['EventItem'])`

Got:

```
idx EventCount
0   6
1   6
2   6
```

How can I get the correct count as follow?

```
idx EventCount
0   2
1   1
2   3
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `.str.len` to get the length of a list, even though lists aren't strings:

```
df['EventCount'] = df['Event'].str.split("/").str.len()
```

Alternatively, the count you're looking for is just 1 more than the count of `"/"`'s in the string, so you could add 1 to the result of `.str.count`:

```
df['EventCount'] = df['Event'].str.count("/") + 1
```

The resulting output for either method:

```
         Event  EventCount
0      abc/def           2
1          abc           1
2  abc/def/hij           3
```

Timings on a slightly larger DataFrame:

```
%timeit df['Event'].str.count("/") + 1
100 loops, best of 3: 3.18 ms per loop

%timeit df['Event'].str.split("/").str.len()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.28 ms per loop

%timeit df['Event'].str.split("/").apply(len)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use `apply` to apply the `len` function to each column:

```
df['EventItem'].apply(len)

0    2
1    1
2    3
Name: EventItem, dtype: int64
```